# Finding (exactly) the electric potential, in presence of non-constant dielectric

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In a medium with homogenous dielectric, the electric field can be solved as an instance of Poisson's equation, but this is not the case in general.

I can find the variational form and solve with computers, but I want to know what exact methods there are to solve the general equation:

$$div(\epsilon \cdot grad(V)) = -\rho$$

where $\epsilon$ and $\rho$ are functions of space, and V is the unknown. I'm most interested in the case where $\epsilon$ is piecewise constant.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience as a theoretical physicist one rarely encounters situations where the dielectric constant is a (continuously varying) function of spatial coordinates. Therefore there is no great need to be able to solve this Maxwell equation analytically for the case of an arbitrarily varying dielectric constant.

On the other hand there are many situations where the dielectric constant assumes different constant values in different regions of space. For example a planar mirror reflecting light. Or a collection of small spherical particles in a liquid solution. These cases are treated by solving the Poisson equation in the different regions of space. This yields general solutions with undetermined parameters. Then boundary conditions are applied to the interface, to find the correct solution. The boundary conditions are derived from the Maxwell equation at a step boundary.